# Automated way to create polygons from coloured map

Tags: qgis, polygon, image

I have a scanned map that has areas of different colours.  I want to create polygons for each area and would like to avoid doing it manually (tracing over the shapes).

Is there a way to do this?  I do not have ArcGIS - am using QGIS.

I have tried various feature extraction options to no success (probably choosing the wrong options).

I have tried creating a layer of just the e.g. blue sections with everything else transparent, importing that, and then polygonising this - but I just get a polygon the size of the whole area.

I have also tried to follow [How to digitize a raster automatically](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/68076/how-to-digitize-a-raster-automatically) (Processing toolbox no longer exists, options I tried in Orfeo unsuccessful); and https://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/training_manual/forestry/stands_digitazing.html (polygons whole area).

I have something like this
[image: example map]

except the colours aren't quite so clear - it's a shaded map overlaying satellite imagery, so there's lots of tiny "gaps", but I can fill these without too much hassle if needed.

Comment: If it's scanned you'll probably need to do a supervised classification https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/228684/supervised-image-classification-in-qgis

Comment: have you tried [ArcScan](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/arcscan/what-is-arcscan-.htm)?

Comment: MichaelStimson - I'll give that a try.  

nxaunxau - I don't have ArcGIS unfortunately, working with open source QGIS.  I'll update the question to make that clear.