# Automatically creating polygon/lines vector from WMTS Raster Building Footprint using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, wmts, vectorization

I have a WMTS layer "EMAP15" http://wmts.nlsc.gov.tw/wmts  providing footprints as raster layer.

I am trying to create 3D LOD1 buildings in Sketchup, but I have to trace each building as vector lines which takes a lot of time (Showed in image purple lines.)

I tried SaveAs GeoTiff first, then use Polygon (Raster to Vector), which does not get clear result of lines or polygon I wanted.

Any ideas?

[image: Manual Trace building Footprints]

Comment: Supervised classification https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/228684/supervised-image-classification-in-qgis might be a good place to start. If that's not where you wish to go you will need to create a binary raster from your TIFF, so **don't save with JPEG compression** as it would *ruin it for interpretation* then find the RGB value of the buildings (hopefully a single colour) and perform conditional statements with the raster calculator https://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_raster/raster_calculator.html before trying to polygonize.