# Finding Rocky Outcrops

Tags: slope, terrain, geology

I've been asked by one of my users if it's possible to find "Rocky Outcrops" in an area. They don't really have a definition for what that means, it's a very open ended question!

My feeling is that this is some sort of "Slope" analysis, combined with a height analysis? We have access to DSM and DTMs from the environment agency as our source data, but this is a new area of GIS for me. Any pointers?

My corporate GIS is Cadcorp, but I can also access QGIS & GRASS if they provide more appropriate functionality.

Answer (score 4):

I would think about using a supervised classification, which will identify all the rocky outcroppings by their image signature.

[Supervised image classification in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/228684/supervised-image-classification-in-qgis)